# FRT construction in the case of super algebras

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, super-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking on papers which are talking about the super quantum algebra osp(2|1). I want to understand how one applies the FRT construction in the case of osp(2|1).
Of course there is a super permutation $P$, but if I'm right, taking a matrix $T$ whose entries represent  the generators of an algebra of functions $A$ on a formal super-group and the universal $R$-matrix of the quantum superalgebra osp(2|1) and writing down the equation $$PR(T\otimes T)=(T\otimes T)PR,$$ I should find the relations defining $A$.
Now, looking what happens when the quantum parameter $q$ of $R$ goes to $1$, I should find the commutation relations between the entries of a matrix in $OSp(2|1)$, but it is not so.
So my question is : are there other sign contributions in the equation$$PR(T\otimes T)=(T\otimes T)PR$$ as those coming from $P$ ?

Comment: May be just guess something like this :  be careful with notation ToT-- may be you should think it leaving in algebra o supermatrices o supermatrices. Hence sign might appear from usual way.  : AoB*CoD=(-1)^sgn(BC)ACoBD.  Ill try to think laater

Comment: I think you're right Alexander. The matrix element of the tensor product of even matrices $\left\{ F_{ij}\right\}$ and  $\left\{ G_{kl}\right\}$ has the form $$(F\otimes G)_{ik,jl}=(−1)^{p(k)(p(i)+p(j))}F_{ij}G_{kl}.$$
